# Using dict.fromkeys(), assign each value to an empty dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've hit a bit of a problem with creating empty dictionaries within dictionaries while using `fromkeys()`; they all link to the same one.

Here's a quick bit of code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
a = dict.fromkeys( range( 3 ), {} )
for key in a:
    a[key][0] = key
```

Output I'd want is like `a[0][0]=0, a[1][0]=1, a[2][0]=2`, yet they all equal `2` since it's editing the same dictionarionary 3 times

If I was to define the dictionary like `a = {0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}}`, it works, but that's not very practical for if you need to build it from a bigger list.

With fromkeys, I've tried `{}`, `dict()`, `dict.copy()` and `b={}; b.copy()`, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Rather than a dictionary indexed by integer, why not a list?

Comment: That honestly didn't cross my mind and I probably could do to be fair haha, though that way would require 8 lines instead of 2, so looks a bit less neat

Comment: `a = [[i] for i in range(3)]`?

Comment: Oh, well in the current state, I need to store 2 'x', 'y', 'z' values for each shape, one for the minimum, one for the maximum. I've got a generator that outputs these values and I just need to assign them to to the dictionary. Currently it's like `a["x"][i],a["y"][i],a["z"][i]=(the generator)`, but I don't think you can append to a list in the same short way

Comment: This is starting to seem like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - perhaps you should explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Well it's for a specific problem of mine, but the question isn't so specific, it's just asking how you'd assign a dictionary to each key, and all I need is the answer to fix what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `{}` is a single value to `fromkeys`, and not a factory. Therefore you get the single mutable dict, not individual copies of it.

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is one way to create a dict that has a builtin factory.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
from pprint import pprint as pp

a = dd(dict)
for key in range(3):
    a[key][0] = key

pp(a)
```

If you want something more strictly evaluated, you will need to use a dict comprehension or map.

```
a = {key: {} for key in range(3)}
```

But then, if you're going to do that, you may as well get it all done

```
a = {key: {0: key} for key in range(3)}
```

Comment: Thanks, so defaultdictionary is basically a dictionary, in that when you give it a key, the value is automatically assigned a new dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over keys and insert a dict for each key:

```
{k: {0: k} for k in keys}
```

Here, `keys` is an iterable of hashable values such as `range(3)` in your example.